# Robolectic in Android with V7 support library issue

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Previously I was uising `ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestAlertDialog()` to test AlertDialog using Robolectric. However, I have updated my UI and now I am using V7 support library. So, it is giving me incompatible types error.

```
  Error:(82, 50) error: incompatible types
required: android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
found:    android.app.AlertDialog
```

is there any solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is easy! Change to:

```
AlertDialog latestAlert = (AlertDialog) ShadowDialog.getLatestDialog()
```